# Comparing contingency table distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, log-linear

I want to compare the distributions of $K$ contingency tables, where each table is $N \times M$.
To make things clearer, let's work on $K=M=N=2$.
Suppose I have a classical cases and controls test, where I have $2$ variables, treated or not, and cured or not.
Suppose that besides testing whether the treatment is effective or not, I want to test whether the effect is different among groups, say males and females. Then I would have $2$ $2 \times 2$ tables, one for males, one for females. I want to test whether the distribution of the tables is independent of sex.

Is there a standard test for this?

Comment: The *contingency table* is quite general as a log linear model. You might, for instance, reject a null of equivalence when table B is the same as table A with all cells doubled. The intensity parameters would be significantly different with sufficient sample size. I suspect that's not what you're after. Could the **odds ratio** be the correct measure of association for comparing tables? Or perhaps the row or column stratum risks?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to construct chi-square tests for this kind of thing, but in general once you move beyond simple comparisons, you probably want to go to loglinear models for contingency tables.

Comment: Any recommended link, book or source on this?

Comment: On loglinear models? There are many good books and online resources, but I'd probably look to say [Agresti](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/) for starters, either book 2 at that link, or book 6 if the first is too much to start with.

Answer (score 1):

This problem might be referred as multiple hypothesis testing. You might have a look for example at *Westfall PH and Young SS "Resampling-based Multiple Testing".* You might start having a look at the wikipedia link about the [Family Wise Error Rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familywise_error_rate) that represents the probability of making one or more false discoveries due to multiple hypothesis testing.

It is usually used when you have many statistical tests $j = 1, \dots, M$, for example Chi-square ones, and thus actually testing $M$ hypothesis $H_0^j$.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is directly related to my question. I don't want to make a global test out of many small ones, but to compare two tables as if they were joint distributions. Something like a KS test for tables